# Get position in relation list

Tags: algorithm, performance, relation

I have a collection of elements. I can relate each element with the other like this:

```
> k=0; for (i=0;i<5;i++) {for (j=i+1;j<5;j++) { console.log(k++, ': ', i, '-', j) } }
0 :  0 - 1
1 :  0 - 2
2 :  0 - 3
3 :  0 - 4
4 :  1 - 2
5 :  1 - 3
6 :  1 - 4
7 :  2 - 3
8 :  2 - 4
9 :  3 - 4
```

My question is:

Given two element indexes, how can I get the position in the relations list?

For example, for `i=1` and `j=2` I want to obtain `4`.

The solution should work for collections of any size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume there are `n` elements and we are looking for relation `i j`. Further assume that `i < j`. We want to know the positions of relation `i j` in the relations list; in other words, we want to know how many relations `k l` come before `i j` in the relations list.

Then we have to answer two questions:

- How many relations `k l` are there with `k` in `[0, ..., i-1]` and `l` any element?
- How many relations `i l` are there with `l` in `[i+1, ..., j-1]`?

The answer to the first question is `i * (i-1) / 2 + i * (n - i)`.

The answer to the second question is `j - i - 1`.

The position in the relations list is the sum of these two values.

Test for correctness in python:

```py
def get_position_in_relations_list(n, i, j):
  assert(j != i)
  if j < i:
    i,j = j,i
  return (i * (2 * n - i - 1)) // 2 + j - i - 1

n = 100
pos = 0
for i in range(n):
  for j in range(i+1,n):
    assert(pos == get_position_in_relations_list(n, i, j))
    pos += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing is called [2D array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/966225/how-can-i-create-a-two-dimensional-array-in-javascript). Just add:

```
var arr = new Array(5); // or n
k = 0;
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    arr[i] = new Array(5); // or n
    for (j = i + 1; j < 5; j++) {
         arr[i][j] = k;
         k++;
    }
}
```

and you've got what you asked for.